# Как менять background-image в зависимости от положения элемента?

Tags: css, css3

Здравствуйте! Имеется вот такое дело: [ссылка на пример jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Aquarius_developer/6xe4seqn/)
Там на месте зеленого прямоугольника использую изображение (background-image), а в этом примере для наглядности обозначил цветом. В общем всю ночь убил, чтобы сделать смену изображения (зеленый прямоугольник) на следующее при его перемещении от пункта к пункту и в обратном порядке. Пытаюсь реализовать на css, т.к. на js пока что не умею толком ничего, но ничего не удается.

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* --- for all three examples ----*/

.nav {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 1em 0 2em;
  width: 25%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #393939;
  transition: .7s;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: #c6342e;
  background-image: url(../test.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0em 0.5em 7px rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.2);
}

.effect {
  position: absolute;
  left: -12.5%;
  transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.nav a:nth-child(1):hover~.effect {
  left: 12.5%;
}

.nav a:nth-child(2):hover~.effect {
  left: 37.5%;
}

.nav a:nth-child(3):hover~.effect {
  left: 62.5%;
}

.nav a:nth-child(4):hover~.effect {
  left: 87.5%;
}


/* ----- line example -----*/

.ph-line-nav .effect {
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 36px;
  background-image: url(../w.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c6342e;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: -45px;
}

.vis-nav {
  border-bottom: 0px solid gray;
  box-shadow: 0em 0.2em 7px rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="ph-line-nav nav vis-nav">
  <a href="#">пункт</a>
  <a href="#">пункт</a>
  <a href="#">пункт</a>
  <a href="#">пункт</a>
  <div class="effect"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.ns {
    touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}


/* html,
body {
    width: 100%;

    height: 100%;
    background-color: #444;
} */

body {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* --- for all three examples ----*/

.nav {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 2em auto;
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
}

.nav a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em 0 2em;
    width: 25%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #393939;
    -webkit-transition: .7s;
    -moz-transition: .7s;
    -o-transition: .7s;
    -ms-transition: .7s;
    transition: .7s;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: #c6342e;
    background: rgba(57, 57, 57, 0.5);

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0em 0.5em 7px rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.2);
}

.effect {
    position: absolute;
    left: -12.5%;
    -webkit-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.nav a:nth-child(1):hover ~ .effect {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 12.5%;
    background: blue;
    /* строчку выше убрать а строчку ниже раскомментировать и вставить свои картинки */
    /* background-image: url(foto/01.jpg); */
    background-size: cover;
    transition:all .5s, left.3s, background .1s;
}

.nav a:nth-child(2):hover ~ .effect {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 37.5%;
    background: white;
    /* строчку выше убрать а строчку ниже раскомментировать и вставить свои картинки */
    /* background-image: url(foto/02.jpg); */
    background-size: cover;
    transition:all .5s, left.3s, background .1s;
}

.nav a:nth-child(3):hover ~ .effect {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 62.5%;
    background: yellow;
    /* строчку выше убрать а строчку ниже раскомментировать и вставить свои картинки */
    /* background-image: url(foto/03.jpg); */
    background-size: cover;
    transition:all .5s, left.3s, background .1s;
}

.nav a:nth-child(4):hover ~ .effect {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 87.5%;
    background: red;
    /* строчку выше убрать а строчку ниже раскомментировать и вставить свои картинки */
     /* background-image: url(foto/04.jpg); */ 
    background-size: cover;
    transition:all .5s, left.3s, background .1s;

}


/* ----- line example -----*/

.effect {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 90px;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 36px;
    background: green;
    /* вот тут не могу в смену изображения */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c6342e;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-left: -45px;
}
.vis-nav {
  border-bottom: 0px solid gray;
  box-shadow: 0em 0.2em 7px rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="ph-line-nav nav vis-nav">
  <a href="#">пункт</a>
  <a href="#">пункт</a>
  <a href="#">пункт</a>
  <a href="#">пункт</a>
  <div class="effect"></div>
</div>
```